# Junit Mockito Mock SessionFactory into DAO Test class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm new in JUnit and Mockito and I want to Mock my SessionFactory inside my DAO Test Class, this is how I proceed:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TodoDaoTest {
    @Mock 
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @InjectMocks 
    TodoDao todoDao;

    @Mock
    Session session;
    @Mock
    Query query;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass(){
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        Mockito.when(query.setParameter(any(int.class), any(Object.class))).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(session.createQuery(any(String.class))).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getTodosByUserIdShouldNotReturnNull(){
        User user = new User();
        assertNotNull(todoDao.getTodosByUserId(user.getId()));
    }
}
```

And this is my DAO Class

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class TodoDao implements ITodoDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @PostFilter("filterObject.userByUserId == authenticationFacade.getAuthenticatedFacade()")
    public List<Todo> getTodosByUserId(int userId) {
        List todos;
        todos = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Todo where userId = ?").setParameter(0, userId).list();
        return todos;
    }
}
```

But I have a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception when I run my test, The nullPointerException is at the level of the line of `todos = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a test I currently have open if I put the `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` after the `Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(...)` I will get `NullPointerException`.

Try doing the init then the mocks.

My understanding is that `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` initialises the stubbed dependencies. This then allows the `when(...).thenReturn(...)` behaviour to be setup on the stubs. If you try set up the behaviour first then the dependencies haven't yet been initialised and hence a NullPointerException.

There is a bit of description in the [javadoc of mockito](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9)

Comment: Thank you I think it resolves my issue. any explanation of this?

Comment: Thanks also to @Sándor Juhos for his suggestions in the response below. it is part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The .createQuery("from Todo where userId = ?") method call returns with null.
You should setup the mocked session too.

Comment: Even with this I have the same issue, (I updated my post to add the Session criteria mock)

Comment: now the .setParameter(0, userId) method call result is null, you should setup the mocked query too.

Comment: Thank you. I added the setParameter mock, but it doesn't resolve my problem. The response of @andrew.b.10 did resolve it after adding all your suggestions.